# How to remove tooltip but keep the 'title' attribute value

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="this is tooltip" title="This is a test">Test</a>
```

Is there a way to remove the tooltip when hovering over the `a` element but still keep the the title attribute value?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pogf203m/)

Comment: It's unclear. what is "tooltip box"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299772/hide-native-tooltip-using-jquery

Comment: sorry forgot to save

Comment: is when i hover on the a it will show a default title box, i will like to remove that.

Comment: May I ask what are you doing with the attribute title?

Comment: Why do you have the title value if you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole purpose of the `title` attribute, is to hold the text for the tooltip, for better accessibility; It is a build in feature in every modern browser.

If you don't want the tooltip functionality, don't use the `title` attribute. You can alternatively use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to attach the textual value to any element, and retrieve it later like so:

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://google.com" data-title="This is a test">Test</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').data('title'); // "This is a test";
```

Comment: The title has 2 uses; a tooltip, and data for screen readers. The OP wants to know how to disable the tooltip without disabling screen readers. Seems like a valid question to me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the title if you want to avoid the tooltip because it was made for this kind of use.

But, if you are using this for content optimization I suggest you to start using microdata with your HTML5 code.

However, you can use JavaScript and CSS to create a simple hack that will save the data in your code but won't show the title for a link. 
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762244/disable-tooltips-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why you need the `title` attribute.

If you need it for screen readers but don't want a tooltip when you hover, you can use

`<a href="This is a tooltip" aria-Label="This is a test">Test</a>`